# Django 1.9: constrain model fields such that both cannot be 'True'

Tags: django, django-models

How can I constrain this model such that `bar` and `baz` cannot both be `True`?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    baz = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Edit: The properties in the fields serve different, but related, purposes. The question arises from working with a large project where replacing bar and baz with a single choice field would require a major rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `super` override the `save` method to enforce logic:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    baz = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.bar and self.baz:
            raise SomeException()
        return super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question as it was asked.  I'm working with a large project that would require a massive rewrite if I combined bar and baz into one choice field, but this approach may be workable.

Answer (score 1):

This would be better suited to a single field with [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices). Examples of this are clothing sizes, genders, subscription levels, etc.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # store the different choices as properties for comparison later
    SMALL = 'small'
    BIG = 'big'

    # group the choices into a list of tuples
    # the first value of the tuple is how they're stored in the database
    # the second value is how they're displayed to the user
    SIZES = (
        (SMALL, 'Small'),
        (BIG, 'Big'),
    )

    # apply the choices to the field with a default
    size = model.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SIZES, default='small')
```

You can then compare them in your views:

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
if foo.size == Foo.SMALL:
    print 'this foo is small'
```

This is a common pattern in Django and can represent the choices in forms using [`ChoiceFields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) and [`ModelChoiceFields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). They're also well supported in the Django Admin app and [`ModelForms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/). These form fields can be rendered using either the dropdown select widget or radio buttons widget.

Comment: This is a good answer if I were designing a project from first principles.  As it is, however, combining the fields is impractical in the project I'm working with.  I need a solution to prevent having to manually check both fields every time a change is made to one of them.

Comment: I understand, but keep in mind that Django 1.8+ has a really excellent model migration system.